# Which Prometheus RabbitMQ Exporter to choose for which RabbitMQ version? How to automate this dependency installation for any version?

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, prometheus

At the time of writing my question the latest RabbitMQ version was 3.7.9 and latest prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter was at 3.7.2.4. So they are different.

How do I know which version of prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter is compatible with RabbitMQ?

Another question is that I have older RabbitMQ at 3.3.5, how do I find the right version of prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter?

Preferable are very simple ways, because I want to automate this.

So my script can take care of prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter for any RabbitMQ version.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter supports RabbitMQ from version 3.6

More details about the support:

https://github.com/deadtrickster/prometheus_rabbitmq_exporter/issues/65